# Recompressing zip - integrity check

Tags: compression, zip, data-integrity

I have multiple large zip files and I would like to recompress them **without** unpacking them (I run the risk of running out of disk space). I am thinking of using `advzip` for that task.

However, I want to ensure that the compressed data is not corrupted in the process. How can I do that?

Obviously, hashing algorithms on the archive won't do here. What is my best option?

**edit:** Platform is CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

You can install info-zip (zip and unzip) (standard package in CentOS) and test the archives

```
unzip -t your_archive.zip
```

This will test the integrity of archives without extract the files inside